# sentinel loop execution in c

Tags: c, loops, sentinel

I have the following code and I would like it to break after entering the sentinel number only once but at the moment I have to input the sentinel number twice for the code to break. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>// Include a standard C Library
#define Sentinel_Numb -1
int main(){

  int ID[360];              
  float seconds[360];
  int i = 0;

 printf("please enter the  ID and how many seconds to calculate enter  -1 when done\n");

while (1)                           
{
    scanf_s("%d",&ID[i]);
    scanf_s("%f",&seconds[i]);

    if( ID[i] == Sentinel_Numb || seconds[i] == Sentinel_Numb){
       break;
         }
    i++;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume `i` is defined and initialized somewhere?

Comment: Doesn't compile... "i" is not defined.

Comment: sorry just edited the question to initialize i

Comment: You should learn [proper c formatting](//prohackr112.tk/proper-c-formatting). It'll encourage people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (1)                           
{
    scanf_s("%d",&ID[i]);

    if (ID[i] == Sentinel_Numb)
        break; 

    scanf_s("%f", &seconds[i]);

    if (seconds[i] == Sentinel_Numb)
        break;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
scanf_s("%d",&ID[i]);
if (ID[i] == Sentinel_Numb)
    break;
scanf_s("%f",&seconds[i]);
if (seconds[i] == Sentinel_Numb)
    break;
```